# min_element in template vector with comparator. Compile error

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a template vector `std::vector<T> beginStore;` and I want to find minimum in that vector. So, first of all I implement it like this:

```
template<typename T, typename Comp = DefaultComp>
//some code
T min = beginStore.at(0);
size_t ind = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < beginStore.size(); ++i) {
    if (Comp::compare(*beginStore.at(i), *min)) {
        min = beginStore.at(i);
        ind = i;
    }
}
```

Where my comparator is:

```
struct DefaultComp {
    template<typename T>
     static bool compare(T a, T b) {
        return a < b;
    }
};
```

Then I want to use all power of C++17 and use std::min_element and std::distance:

```
auto min = std::min_element(beginStore.begin(),beginStore.end(),Comp::compare);
auto ind = std::distance(beginStore.begin(),min);
```

Then it error like this:

> no matching function for call to 'min_element'
> auto min = std::min_element(beginStore.begin(),beginStore.end(),Comp::compare);

I have already try `std::greater`, implement `operator()`, use different comparator like this:

```
struct myclass {
    template<typename T>
    bool operator() (T i,T j) { return i<j; }
} myobj;
```

But I can't get success.
**UPD** I'm sorry that confuse you, but vector contains pointers. Rewrite std::distance. Really, it was not what I want.

Comment: Post the entire code and the entire error.

Comment: `Comp::compare(*beginStore.at(i), *min)` shouldn't compile, unless `beginStore` is in fact a vector of pointers, and you are looking for the smallest pointed-to value. Show the code you are actually compiling; prepare a [mcve]. If you do have a vector of pointers, then for `std::min_element` you'd need to adapt the comparison function to dereference the pointers and compare pointed-to values.

Comment: `Comp::compare` is a function template - an infinite family of functions. You need to pass a specific instance to `std::min_element`. This should compile: `auto min = std::min_element(beginStore.begin(),beginStore.end(),Comp::compare<decltype(beginStore.front())>);`

Comment: Note that `std::distance(beginStore.begin(),beginStore.end())` is the same as `beginStore.size()`. Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DefaulComp::compare` is template, so you cannot pass it that way to `std::min_element`.

either provide type

```
std::min_element(beginStore.begin(), beginStore.end(), &Comp::compare<int>);
```

or wrap it in functor:

```
std::min_element(beginStore.begin(),
                 beginStore.end(),
                 [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return Comp::compare(lhs, rhs); });
```

Comment: Yeah, the second is worked, but then I had to replace compare in my comparator to      `static bool compare(T a, T b) {
        return *a < *b;
    }`

Comment: You don't need to change `compare`, you can dereference in the adaptor: `[](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return Comp::compare(*lhs, *rhs); }`. You should have mentioned in your question that `beginStore` holds pointers; `typename T = int` strongly suggests otherwise, rendering your question quite confusing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik oh yes, thank you, really, it was a rude mistake that define T as int!

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson: I use the template argument here, not the one similar to `std::less` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a struct comparer, when you can use lambdas (delegates) like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(1000);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::rand);

    std::cout << *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a < b; }) << std::endl;
    std::cout << *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a < b; }) << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Lambdas are part of the C++11 standard!

Cheers

Comment: For that comparer, `std::less` is enough (and can even be omitted as default).